# Add jpg-image to database MVC Core Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, entity

I am trying to add images (jpeg) to my database. The SQL-code seems right (I have compared it to many examples at StackOverflow). But I don't know how to proceed with the Controller or the View. I am working with the latest version of Visual Studio and with MVC Core.

Here is the Model:

```
public class Product
{
   [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an product name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify a category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public string SubCategory { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required
    (ErrorMessage = "Please enter a positive price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    public string ImageSourceFileName { get; set; }

    public string ImageContentType { get; set; }

}
```

Here is the database:

```
    ProductID   int False   
    Category    nvarchar(MAX)   False   
    Description nvarchar(MAX)   False   
    Name    nvarchar(MAX)   False   
    Price   decimal(18,2)   False   
    SubCategory nvarchar(MAX)   True    
    Image   varbinary(MAX)  True    
    ImageContentType    nvarchar(MAX)   True    
    ImageSourceFileName nvarchar(MAX)   True
```

Here is the view (so far...):

```
           <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Image" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Image" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Image" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ImageSourceFileName" class=
            "control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ImageSourceFileName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ImageSourceFileName" class=
            "text-danger"></span>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ImageContentType" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ImageContentType" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ImageContentType" class=
            "text-danger"></span>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
            </form>
```

I would like to have an choose file-button, a post-button. I am almost ready with my website so this is one of the last steps to finish it. I want all the product information in the website, including images, to be able to foreach-through all the products in the online-shop.

Comment: [File uploads in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads)

Comment: you are storing images in binary format in database right